# how to use connect-orientdb module with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orientdb, nosql

My goal is to connect my server code that its with nodejs and expressjs framework to my database that is with orientdb.
first of all i wanted to store my sessions in database. but i had difficulty connecting my server to database.

the error that i get when i execute server.js:

```
  /Users/soroush/Desktop/nodeOrient/node_modules/connect-orientdb/lib/connect-orientdb.coffee:191
    })(connect.session.Store);
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
  at module.exports (/Users/soroush/Desktop/nodeOrient/node_modules/connect-orientdb/lib/connect-orientdb.coffee:22:46)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/soroush/Desktop/nodeOrient/server.js:8:48)
  at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
  at startup (node.js:160:18)
  at node.js:449:3
```

and my server.js code is:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cs = require("coffee-script/register"),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    config = require('./config/config.js'),
    orientDBStore = require('connect-orientdb')(session),
    OrientDB = require('orientjs'),
    orientDBConfig = {
        server : {
            host: "localhost",
            port:2424
        },
        db : {
            user_name: "admin",
            user_password: "admin"
        },
        database : "sessions",
        class_name : "sessions_class"
    },
    server  = OrientDB({
    hose : "localhost",
    port : "2424",
    username : "root",
    password : "root"
    })
    ;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public' )));

app.use(cookieParser());

require('./routes/route.js')(express, app);

    app.use(session({
        secret:"mySecret",
        store: new orientDBStore(orientDBConfig)
    }));

app.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log("app is listening on port 8000");
})
```

**my main problem is that the connect-orientdb was used when the session module was builtin in express, but now that session is a different module i have occurred to this problem.**

Comment: Seems like one of your values with property of 'store' is undefined.

Comment: @OleksandrGubchenko yeah, thats the problem, but i'v checked other DBs like mongoDB that they'v used this method, and didn't have  this problem. the store property is defined in connect-mongodb module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for it if anyone faced this problem:

```
var session = require('express-session'),
    OrientoStore = require('connect-oriento')(session);

app.use(session({
        secret: 'SomeSecret',
        store: new OrientoStore({
            server: "host=localhost&port=2424&username=dev&password=dev&db=test"
        })
    }));
```

for more info this [github link](https://github.com/ventu-io/connect-oriento) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide for ExpressJS in OrientDB: [Blog Tutorial with ExpressJS and OrientDB](https://github.com/gabipetrovay/node-orientdb/wiki/Blog-Tutorial-with-ExpressJS-and-OrientDB).

And [try to use](https://github.com/gabipetrovay/node-orientdb/wiki/Blog-Tutorial-with-ExpressJS-and-OrientDB#making-the-routes-use-orientdb):

```
orientDBStore = require('orient')(session),
```

instead of:

```
orientDBStore = require('connect-orientdb')(session),
```

Comment: orient is a different module, i was using this [link : npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-orientdb) to use connect-orientdb module, but with some changes that now the session module is not a builtin module in expressjs, i have required it separately.

Comment: my main problem is that the connect-orientdb was used when the session module was builtin in express, but now that session is a different module i have occurred to this problem.

Comment: it's not official module, so it might be outdated